# Can a cancelled alarm still switch on the phone even when it's off?

Tags: security, alarm, power-on

After searching I know that some phones if you set up an alarm then you switch the phone off, it will open up exactly at the time you set it up to ring this is in case if the alarm is active before you switch off the phone.

But what happened with me is I set up an alarm and then I just cancelled it "but without deleting it or changing the date or the time" and I turned off my phone. But still it opened up exactly at the time I set up the alarm as if the alarm still active. I just want to understand why this happened? Is this a common thing in Android or it indicates to something else?

Also some of the alarms I set don't ring exactly at the time I set them to but after a couple of minutes or so. I also I don't understand why it's happening?

Comment: By turning off, do you mean a short press on the power button?  Or a long press on the power button and then pressing power off on the screen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes a long press on the power button and pressing power off.

Comment: Normal Android devices don't have the ability to switch themself on after powering it off. If your device has such a ability it has been added by the manufacturer. And of course the manufacturer may have implemented it with bugs, so anything can happen. That common appointment notifications come too late is usually just because if Android battery saving which accumulates events so some events are delayed to be processed together with other events.